# Azure App Service Instrumentation Profiling?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

It looks as though it's possible to [use instrumentation profiling on an Azure Cloud Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-performance-profiling-cloud-services/) application, but I'm not seeing a way to do the same with an Azure App Service. The only [options](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-profiling-support-in-azure-app-service/) I've found allowed `sampling` profiling.

What methods are available for instrumentation profiling of an Azure App Service?

Comment: I've also asked this question on the MSDN forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f3cd8f98-db74-484a-93d1-f059cff3ba5b/instrumentation-profiling?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview#f3cd8f98-db74-484a-93d1-f059cff3ba5b

Comment: Hey, are there any updates? I'm trying to do the same but currently only option is to do that locally.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Service Profiler is now available as part of Application Insights. It does work with App Services. You can read my review about it here to learn more:

https://stackify.com/azure-service-profiler-review/

It works well with ASP.NET web apps. It can help you find slow methods and stuff going on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

We have the performance testing tool of Visual Studio Online integrated into Azure App Services. [Checkout the blog about Performance Testing on Azure App Services.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-app-performance-test/)

We also have Remote Profile on Azure App Services now, [Check this blog out for more details on Remote Profiling](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-profiling-support-in-azure-app-service/)

There is a good Azure Friday Video on Remote Profiling on Azure App Services as well, [Check the video here.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Remote-Profiling-in-Azure-with-Hamid-Saffi)