# Prevent Azure App Service from viewing backend configuration

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a project that has us deploying to an Azure Web Site.

The code is overall working and now we are focusing more on security.

Right now we are having an issue that back end configuration files are visible with the direct URL.

Examples (Link won't work):

- https://myapplication.azurewebsite.net/foldername/FileName.xml (this
  file is in a folder that is contained within the root application)
- https://myapplication.azurewebsite.net/vApp/FileName.css (this file
  is a part of virtual application sub folder)

I have found this to be true with multiple extensions and locations.

Extensions like:

- .css
- .htm
- .xml
- .html
- the list likely goes on

I understand that certain files are downloaded to the client side and that those can't be stopped. However backend XML files are something we don't pass to the client (especially if has connection strings).

I did read a similar article, [Azure App Service Instrumentation Profiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072816/azure-app-service-instrumentation-profiling)

However this didn't directly relate to my issue.

Any insight would extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not store sensitive information in flat files, especially under your site root. Even if you `web.config` it *just right* you're still one botched commit away from disaster.

Use **Application Settings** instead, that's what they're for.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure

Comment: thank you for that advice, we are looking into that for our connection strings. We also have whole folders that utilize the above extensions and we need to block those from being publicly accessible. So this applies to non-connection string code, like metadata information. If this isn't possible from a base app service can we use a L7 device in front of it?

Comment: It is possible - Use something like Request Filtering (IIS): http://serverfault.com/a/37786/176806